# Dependency injection with constructor chaining

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Currently I have a simple generic abstract class with one service parameter in constructor which is resolved by dependency injection.

```cs
public abstract class CosmosCommandHandler<T>
{
    protected readonly ICosmosStore<T> _cosmosStore;

    protected CosmosCommandHandler(ICosmosStore<T> cosmosStore)
    {
      _cosmosStore = cosmosStore;
    }
}
```

and some concrete class inheriting from it

```cs
public class FooCommandHandler : CosmosCommandHandler<Foo> 
{
  private readonly IFooService _fooService;

  public FooCommandHandler(ICosmosStore<Foo> cosmosStore, IFooService fooService) 
      : base(cosmosStore)
  {
    _fooService = fooService;
  }
}
```

This is all fine, but I want to add a new service to abstract class and resolve it with DI as well. My idea is that I should use constructor chaining for this, but it's not working out.
Something like this.

```cs
public abstract class CosmosCommandHandler<T>
{
    private readonly IAuditService _auditService;
    protected readonly ICosmosStore<T> _cosmosStore;

    private CosmosCommandHandler(ICosmosStore<T> cosmosStore, IAuditService auditService)
    {
        _cosmosStore = cosmosStore;
        _auditService = auditService;
    }

    protected CosmosCommandHandler(ICosmosStore<T> cosmosStore) 
        : this(cosmosStore, IAuditService auditService)
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously I could just pass the `IAuditService` from `FooCommandHandler` just like `ICosmosStore`, but that doesn't seem right as `FooCommandHandler` has nothing to do with `IAuditService`. It is out of its scope.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: No, what you are asking is not possible. You can use composition instead of inheritance for this.

Comment: If `FooCommandHandler` doesn't require `IAuditService` then I would question your design.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `IAuditService` is like a logger and everything around it would be implemented only in base class. It is lower level. Command handlers shouldn't know anything about this service as it would be handled entirely in base class. Seems OK to me, but if you still think it's questionable, could you elaborate?

Comment: Derived classes are by design tightly coupled to their base classes and therefore your assumption about Command handlers not knowing anything about this service is very shaky. Even if we ignored the constructor problem you found youself, if you e.g. override any of the base methods, you still need to call base to do its work with the logging, right? So the command handler actually does secretly know. Otherwise you have a base class where you don't override anything in the derived classes, which once again begs the question of why don't you use composition instead?

Comment: In your design `FooCommandHandler` **is** a `CosmosCommandHandler<Foo>`, so to instantiate a `FooCommandHandler`, you need to provide an `IAuditService`. If `FooCommandHandler` **requires** a `CosmosCommandHandler<Foo>` then use composition.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek , JohnathanBarclay Thank you! You are right. Base class in this case (so far) was just containing syntactic sugar to make DB calls from handlers/controllers simpler. I will use composition.

Answer (score 0):

If `IAuditService` is out of the `FooCommandHandler` scope, then create child of your `CosmosCommandHandler` class which will have that `IAuditService`. And that child also could be abstract class.
Also, you could create additional overloaded constructor for your `CosmosCommandHandler` class - and that `FooCommandHandler` class does not need to use it. But that also breaks the concept of inheritance because `FooCommandHandler` class has nothing to do with `IAuditService`.